# How can I allow computers on one router to access computers on another router?

Tags: router, nat, static-routes

I have a lousy 3801HGV modem/router that I have to use with AT&T UVerse.  Due to AT&T issues, that router does not allow the ability to change DNS settings.  I have added a LinkSys E1200 as a second router in order to use OpenDNS settings (to filter content to my kids).  I still have machines that I want to run on the 3801 and they sometimes need to communicate with machines behind the E1200.  The problem is that the 3801 doesn't seem to allow any sort of static routing.  Let's say I wanted to do file sharing with two machines behind the E1200.  Any thoughts on how to configure that?

Comment: A comment would be helpful on the -1.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can either have two LANs or you can have one. There really aren't solutions in between.

Comment: I think they downvoted on the filtering of the internet to your kids. I wouldn't downvote - but I don't agree :).

Comment: Check if the 3801HGV supports the so called bridge mode (or modem mode) in which it would act only as a modem. Then install DD-WRT on the Linksys (I think it supports it), and then you can create 2 separate networks on the Linksys, put all machines behind the Linksys on the respective networks.

Comment: @lupincho Yes, the 3801HGV does support bridge mode via DMZPlus.  I'll check out the DD-WRT because the E1200 out of the box doesn't support multiple networks.

Comment: @lupincho - If you add an answer, I will give you credit for it.  I ended up using DMZPlus and putting everything behind the Linksys.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off rethinking your entire solution, there are no winners in meddling with ISP firmware.

What I do is have my computer connected to both devices at once, (windows lets you configure adapter priority in the advanced settings of ncpa.cpl , so you can choose which network card will be the default route for internet requests). Therefore my family is setup on one router, and I'm on both, default route no filtering, but they can access my shares, and we can play multilayer LAN Games, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about your ISP modem. It's about as useful as a paper-weight.

I would recommend, and can comment that this works, buying 2 Linksys routers and install DD-WRT on them. I have found that residential routers either have internal static routing disabled or broken. After I installed DD-WRT - everything worked great. This would work great if you have 2 public IPs, if not then you will need to set the gateway of router 2 to router 1.

[ This is a question for the network experts - if you set the gateway of router 2 to router 1 - do you still need static routes? ]

So:

Router 1 - 192.168.1.X

Router 2 - 192.168.2.X

Then using DD-WRT you can set static routing between the subnets.

What you really want is a proxy. I know of a co-worker who uses IPcop ( http://www.ipcop.org/2.0.0/en/admin/html/ ) - although it may be overkill for this situation. I think all you need is squid setup to filter out keywords you don't like ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software) ). I'm sure it could be setup as a service so all you need to do is tell your kid "if you want to surf just turn on this computer".